# Statically linking GLFW to CMake to an executable

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake, glfw

In my project, I would like to statically link GLFW to my main executable, but when I try to I do not get any error from my CMakeLists, and the error from my main executable is just saying that GLFW/glfw3.h file is not a valid file.

Here is my CMakeLists.txt code:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(openGL VERSION 1.0.0)


set(GLFW_BUILD_DOCS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_TESTS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

add_subdirectory(L:\glfw-3.3.2)

add_executable(main main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(main glfw)

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(main OpenGL::GL)
```

And my main executable:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

using namespace std;


int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Exact error code:

```
cannot open source file "GLFW/glfw3.h/"
```

Comment: add_subdirectory is for building another cmake project, you'll also need to specify it in your target link libraries. Depending on how it's setup, you may also have to specify target_include_directories

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I am very amateur with CMake so is there something else I could use instead of add_subdirectory?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to @ you @OMGtechy

Comment: I wouldn't worry about that too much at this stage, it was mostly a passing comment. The main takeaway there was that it won't setup your include paths. Sometimes target_link_libraries does that (depending on how the subproject is setup), sometimes you need to manually specify them. If you could modify your example to be self contained, people might be able to help more. Reducing the problem to a smaller project might make that easier (it's not clear where the myapp target comes from, for example).

Comment: The name of the file in the error message `GLFW/glfw3.h/` - doesn't correspond to name in your `#include` directive - `GLFW/glfw3.h`. The names differ in tail slash. Also, the error message usually includes location of the erroneous line. This is important information, and it should also be included into the question post.